# use event.stopPropagation on sidebar list menu except dropdown button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adminlte

First thanks in advance for your help. I'm using body click to close sidebar when you click anywhere in body including the sidebar menu list. i want to disable body click on a dropdown menu only li in list menu.

1- I used this code for the body click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Click event on body hide the element
$("#col-click1").click(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < (991) && $("body").hasClass("sidebar-open")) {
    $("body").removeClass('sidebar-open');

  }
});
});
```

2- To disable the body click event on li that open th dropdown menu i tried to use thebelow code, but i know it's doesn't. I'm looking to alternative solution as i'm new using jquery.

```
 <li ui-sref-active="active" id="demo222" class="sidebar-only"><a data-       target="#demo2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success sidebar-only" data-toggle="dropdon" data-parent="#MainMenu"><img src="/app/img/icons/candidate_settings.png" id="input_img0">Mon compte</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"  id="demo2">
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a style="color: #7c868d !important; font-weight: 400 !important;" href="" style="cursor: pointer;" class="list-group-item">compte</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a style="color: #7c868d !important; font-weight: 400 !important;" href="" style="cursor: pointer;" class="list-group-item">Support</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a style="color: #7c868d !important; font-weight: 400 !important;" href="" class="list-group-item" ng-click="logout()">Se sign out</a></li>
</div>

   $('#demo222').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use class and changed class, and add event onm this class 'class="changed-item"':

```
         <li ui-sref-active="active" class="changed-item" id="demo222" class="sidebar-only"><a data-       target="#demo2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success sidebar-only" data-toggle="dropdon" data-parent="#MainMenu"><img src="/app/img/icons/candidate_settings.png" id="input_img0">Mon compte</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-menu"  id="demo2">
    <li ui-sref-active="active" class="changed-item"><a style="color: #7c868d !important; font-weight: 400 !important;" href="" style="cursor: pointer;" class="list-group-item">compte</a></li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active" class="changed-item"><a style="color: #7c868d !important; font-weight: 400 !important;" href="" style="cursor: pointer;" class="list-group-item">Support</a></li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active" class="changed-item"><a style="color: #7c868d !important; font-weight: 400 !important;" href="" class="list-group-item" ng-click="logout()">Se sign out</a></li>
    </div>
```

Open dial by class="changed-item" selector:

```
$('.change-item').click(function () {
   //open dialog
})

and not active you can toggle this class:

$("body").removeClass('changed-item');
```

and you will not use event.stopPropagation();

Comment: Hi #Enlightener thans for your reply, but i already find a solution that's works fine. i just applied the click event on specefic classes not on body.